# Collapsing an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to have this method take in an array and add every 2 numbers together(doesn't add the same number twice) and make a new array to return, if there is an an odd number of elements the odd number will be added at the end. It currently doesn't add the correct numbers.

code:

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] arrayToCollapse) {

    // Properties
    int[] newArray = new int[(arrayToCollapse.length / 2) + (arrayToCollapse.length % 2)];

    // Set each elements for the new array.
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayToCollapse.length / 2 ; i++) {

        // Set the current index of the new array to the next two elements of the passed in array.
        newArray[i] += arrayToCollapse[i * 2] + arrayToCollapse[i * 2];

    }

    // Set the last element of the new array if the array passed in was odd.
    if(arrayToCollapse.length % 2 == 1) {

        newArray[newArray.length - 1] = arrayToCollapse[arrayToCollapse.length - 1];

    }

    // Return the array
    return newArray;

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code presented? Please [edit] the post and describe the exact problem.

Comment: The `reduce` and `filter`functions are your friends

Comment: `newArray[i] = arrayToCollapse[i * 2] + arrayToCollapse[i * 2 + 1];`

Comment: Sadly I cannot use those because I cannot go past where I am at in the book for my class.

Comment: Thanks @Johnny, I saw the answer below as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```java
newArray[i] += arrayToCollapse[i * 2] + arrayToCollapse[i * 2];
```

Should be:

```java
newArray[i] = arrayToCollapse[i * 2] + arrayToCollapse[(i * 2) + 1];
```